# MFMailComposeViewController : subject/text non editable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I need to work on an application able to send a mail with automatic content (subject/text) that the user shouldn't be allowed to edit. Is it possible to do ?

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "no".  If you want to use the MFMailComposeViewController class, you have to pay attention to this paragraph in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Important** The mail composition interface itself is not customizable
>   and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after
>   presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make
>   further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the
>   content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored.
>   Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the
>   interface.

The user can (and should be able to) change anything and everything s/he wishes before they send out an e-mail.

If you don't want to follow those rules Apple set, there are other mail frameworks you can use within your iOS app.

Comment: Glad I could help! I just wanted to make sure you don't waste your time trying to break the rules of MFMailComposeViewController, because Apple would (very likely) reject your app in that case (which would be a big drag for everyone).